# Select from another select without temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is table of numbers containing values [1,1,2,3,7,3,4,2,7]
I want to select only duplicates so output set would contain [1,2,3,7] so 4 is filtered out.

I have code that I did like this:

```
DROP TABLE #tempTable;
SELECT  [numbers] as nums, COUNT(*) as cny
INTO #tempTable
  FROM [testBase].[dbo].[numbers] group by numbers;

SELECT nums from #tempTable where nums > 1;
```

Now I would like to know if I can get it without first selecting to #tempTable?
Something more like select from select or is it only way I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same in one query.

Conditions that are made after **GROUP BY** should be added to **HAVING** clause.

```
SELECT  [numbers] as nums, COUNT(*) as cny
FROM [testBase].[dbo].[numbers] 
GROUP BY numbers
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

More on this

[HAVING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)

[Having clause tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/having.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT [numbers] AS NUM
FROM TAB_NAME
HAVING COUNT([numbers]) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select count(numbers) from TABLE group by numbers having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having` clause. `Having` specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate function used in SELECT statement.. So in the `having clause` you can Filter the distinct rows.

```
SELECT [numbers]
FROM   [testBase].[dbo].[numbers]
GROUP  BY [numbers]
HAVING Count([numbers]) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT numbers FROM 
 numbers
 GROUP BY numbers 
 having Count(numbers) >= 2
```